# CSS Scaled Image Jagged/Pixelated on Opacity Transition

Tags: html, css

I have a larger image that is being scaled down to thumbnail size, and on hover the opacity will change using a CSS3 transition. It becomes jagged and pixelated for the duration of the transition and then goes back to normal. I have tried using backface visibility but that doesn't seem to be doing anything, though I could be doing it wrong.

Why is this happening?

```css
a img {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s; 
}
a img:hover { 
  opacity: 0.7; 
}
```

```html
<h4>Large image scaled small</h4>
<a href="">
  <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/1U0b1p1k1j1q0v2p0v2S/01.jpg" width="100" />
</a>

<h4>Small image no scale</h4>
<a href="">
  <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/253s3p1k0I2z3A081P2w/01.png" width="100" />
</a>
```

Comment: How large are the images you are using for those thumbnails?

Comment: Fiddle added to original post

I believe @npage is correct in his reply below (though not every image does the pixelation for me)—But how is one to have a responsive site with responsive images if the browser can't handle them with transitions.

I wonder if there is a work around to this?

Comment: There is nothing responsive about your code.

Comment: It would be best to have multiple size versions of your images.

Comment: Ummm right @ Tiny Giant because it's a minimum sample of the problem I'm having.

The problem is in FF and Chrome, it looks like Safari doesn't have the issue, it's probably applying something to smooth to images when scaled.

Answer (score 1):

During an animation, the browsers are redrawing the affected objects. In order to keep this process efficient and battery-friendly, browsers will use a different rendering method so the redraw is quicker.

Since CSS animations are still relatively new, I would expect browsers to improve over time. Until then, you can try to force the browser to use a different rendering method via CSS image-rendering property:

```
img
{
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

Note, this is still experimental and current iterations of browsers require various prefixed attributes, which will likely break and change in the future as standards are created. Here are a few options available at the time of writing:

```
img
{
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; 
}
```

I've also noticed some people tricking the browser to always use the other rendering functions by applying a seemingly pointless CSS transformation property, like so:

```
img
{
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

This effectively does nothing to how the image is portrayed, except that the browser will use a different rendering method which should mask the animation effect starting and ending.