# CSS transform on image getting pixelated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm resizing an image with setting the width/height dynamicly with css and using transform duration to smooth this process. However it is working but once the animation started the image gets pixelated. Occurs in Firefox and Chrome, i didnt test any other browsers.

Comment: I don't think any browsers continually smooth an image as it resizes it. However, if you instead use `transform` properties in CSS to scale it it should look a lot better. e.g. `transform: scale(1.5);`. Added bonus: `transform` properties also obey `transition` rules!

Comment: It might help to apply the transformations to an `img` element rather than a `div` with a `background-image`. You also don't need to set both the width and height, just set a width and apply the transformation to that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33353614/1028949

Comment: @Quantastical once ill add this css its already loading with pixelated edges and stays like this even when transforming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height is fixed, before and after the resize, it could have something to do with it?

Try and amend the javascript to also set the final height of the div, if you want to maintain aspect ratio, see http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

from the initial 350x64 the final dimension should be 250x46